# How to rewrite Headless Autodesk Forge Viewer in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, autodesk-forge

I'm trying to write the ES6 version of the Headless Forge Viewer implemented in this link:
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/headless/

I've installed the npm package for the Forge Viewer, and I succeed to do most of the code till I reached these two lines:

```
var modelNodes = viewerApp.bubble.search(av.BubbleNode.MODEL_NODE); // 3D designs
        var sheetNodes = viewerApp.bubble.search(av.BubbleNode.SHEET_NODE); // 2D designs
```

I don't know how to define the "av" in Typescript.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: title ... `Viewer in ES6` ... then in question `how to define the "av" in Typescript.` - so which language do you want? javascript ES6 or TypeScript (they're two different things)

Comment: so, what **is** `av`?

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out the answer, just replace the av with Autodesk.Viewing and everything work as a charm :)